# Error Not Found message when uploading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I have installed this jQuery File Upload and I am getting the following error message (just below the image thumbnail) when storing jpg images to server.

**Error Not Found**

NOTE: This error occurs for all 5 tabs:

-Basic

-Basic Plus

-Basic Plus UI

-AngularJS

-jQuery UI

This is the error message in the browser console:

**jquery-1.12.1.min.js:4 
POST http://localhost/blueimptest/vendor/blueimp-file-upload/server/php/ 404 (Not Found)**

I have double-checked the folder and the file structure that is returning a 404 exists. Changing the file path from 'server/php/' to 'server/php' in the main.js file eliminates the 404 error but returns this (with no error in the browser):

**Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

I have not edited any of the code. I am using the index.php file that exists in the plugins folder (to use the Basic Plus UI). The progress bar and image preview features work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. After looking in the main.js file again there is an unnecessary function that breaks the program. Once deleted, It worked.